# MongoDB $expr compare field in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
{
name: 'product A',
min_price: 5,
max_price: 15,
stores: [
 {name: 'A', price: 6},
 {name: 'B', price: 4}
]
},
{
name: 'product B',
min_price: 9,
max_price: 14,
stores: [
 {name: 'C', price: 12},
 {name: 'B', price: 10}
]
}
```

How can I find product have store's price $lt min_price?
I tried:

```
{$expr: { $lt: [ "$min_price", "$stores.price"] }}
```

Seems like I am doing it wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you just need to add [$min](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) into the batch:

```
{$expr: { $lt: [ "$min_price", {$min: "$stores.price"} ] }}
```